# Python user-defined exceptions placement and catching

Tags: python, exception

I'm new to Python and I'm not sure what's the best place to put my user-defined exceptions, and where to catch them.

For example, I have a program which starts a game, when the game is stopped, an user-defined exception is raised (StopGame). I should catch this exception from outside the game since the game is throwing this exception. Though, the exception is specific to the game so the definition of the exception should be in the game module (or maybe the game package?).

Here is the simple layout of the program:

**Program structure**:

```
__main__.py
game/
    __init__.py
    game.py
```

***_*_main_*_*.py**

```
import game

def main():
    g = game.Game()

    try:
        g.start()
    except game.StopGame:
        print '\nbye bye!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**game/*_*_init_*_*.py**

```
from game import Game
from game import StopGame
```

**game/game.py**

```
class Game:

    def start(self):

        try:
            a = raw_input('do you want to play?\n')
            print 'cool'
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError):
            raise StopGame

        if a == 'no':
            raise StopGame
        else:
            print 'cool'

class StopGame(Exception):
    pass
```

This code works fine like this, I'm just not sure this is the way to go. What I find somewhat disappointing is that I should import every exception in game/**_*init*_**.py using this setup. Otherwise I should catch the exception like:

```
except game.game.StopGame
```

Which looks a bit nasty. I think it's better to be able to reach all the attributes in the module 'game' from the variable 'game' in **_*main*_**.py. Then I know you can put this in game/**_*init*_**.py:

```
from game import *
```

Which will import all classes from game/game.py, but I heard that using * for importing is a bad practice.

So, my question is, what is the best way to do this? Maybe my whole setup is wrong, if so, I would like to hear what's the correct setup.

Thanks a lot in advance!

BTW: If you might wonder why I have a game module inside a game package: the idea is that the package will contain a lot of more modules that are related to the game, game/game.py is just the initiator of the whole game, maybe I should put that code into game/**_*init*_**.py?

Comment: Do you think `StopGame` should be an error?

Comment: How should I stop the game otherwise? I can let Game() return false or something, but then I should build this return mechanism in every deeper layer from Game() where the game might be wished to be stopped.

Comment: @Blender Considering `SystemExit` is an exception, I think that `StopGame` being one too makes sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## How is it done elsewhere?

I think that the best way to answer your issue is to look at an actual Python package and see how it's built. I'll take the example of the [excellent python-requests package](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/tree/master/requests).

This module is about making HTTP requests. Yours is about playing a game.

Basic HTTP requests functionality is imported in the `requests/__init__.py` file, but is defined elsewhere. That's what you're doing, but the 'elsewhere' could have a better name. Maybe `game/core.py` could be a good fit.

Exceptions are defined in the `requests/exceptions.py` file. It's usually appropriate for a relatively-small package to have all the exceptions in one place.
Note that the exceptions are imported into `requests/__init__.py` too! This makes them easier to import in other packages that might need to catch them!

Last, no `from module import *` is used. It's not going to take so much time to actually add exactly what's needed, so you should avoid `*`.

---

## What can you do in your case?

- Avoid having a `game/game.py` file, call it `game/core.py` or something
- For a small package, put your exceptions in a `game/exceptions.py` file
- In `game/__init__.py`, import what's usually needed from your package: the main classes and the exceptions.

Comment: Thanks man, that really clears things up! Using a separate module to put all exceptions in looks like a good idea. I'll also take a extensive look at the requests package. Also the rename suggestion to core sounds like a good idea, thank you!

Comment: This requests package as an exemplar is a great tipp even ten years later, thank you! I will share here the currently most used fork from github, which is probably to be the preferred exemplar link: https://github.com/psf/requests